# InvalidValueError: unknown property adress

Tags: vue.js, geocoder

I'm getting this error when trying to set a new map center using the Geocoder Api from Google Maps.

```
geocoder.geocode({adress:this.startPosition},
    (results2,status)=>{
      if(status=="OK"){
        this.map.setCenter(results2[0].geometry.location)
        alert(results2[0].geometry.location)
      }else{
        alert("Geocode was not sucessfull" + status)
      }
    });
```

where "startPosition" is a string with my location

Comment: Should it be `address`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `adress`, it should be `address`.